# sizeof vs std::is_same comparison

Tags: c++, c++11

I am currently working on a simple library that has special data structures. When using the data the classes proxy the comparison request to a generic proxy class that contains all the operator overloads. Since some of the data classes are different lengths, I have if statements checking the data type for if it should compare that byte location.

Currently I am using `sizeof()` to compare the sizes of the two data structures being operated on. If they are bigger than `X` then they can be calculated on for byte `X - 1`.

Example comparison:

```
if ((sizeof(lhsVT) / sizeof(lhsT) > 2) && (sizeof(rhsVT) / sizeof(rhsT) > 2))
where lhsVT is the lefthand class & lhsT is the lefhand type,
and rhsVT is the righthand class & rhsT is the righthand type.
```

However, using `std::is_same` will yield the same comparison

```
if (std::is_same<lhsVT<lhsT>, class<lhsT>>::value &&
    std::is_same<rhsVT<rhsT>, class<rhsT>>::value)
where class is the class it needs to be to continue operation.
```

My question is since they both have the same functionality for me, which will be more efficent/benefitial for me to use.

Comment: Show both fragments to someone uninvolved and ask what each one does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both those cases will be completely optimized out, and the `if` block will either be written or not at compile time.

I'd go for the more semantic case (`is_same`), but up to you. You seem pretty masochistic.

Comment: Thank you, I assumed as much, but I wanted a second opinion. Yes I am pretty masochistic, but I am leaning towards an `is_same` approach (due to the fact that the template template operators actually do not work with the `sizeof` approach).